# Rails 3 - routes for admin section

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, model, admin

I am building my first admin section in Rails and I am struggling with routing problems.
My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
  get "admin/menuh"
  get 'admin/welcome'
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    resources :menuh
    resources :menuv
    resources :welcome
  end
```

And my `views` structure looks like **views/admin/users/*files***. If I will set to url address of browser the url **localhost:3000/admin/users/new**, so I will get the error message **No route matches {:controller=>"users"}** (it's in the file **views/admin/users/_form.html.erb** - this file is generated by scaffold)... so I would like to ask you - where is the problem? Is here anything important, what I am disregarding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set up your `form_for` like this, I reckon:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

Because the route is in a namespace, you need to tell the form that also:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
```

That should help you fix that issue.